# Integrating the Kumaraswamy PDF to generate the CDF

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to rationalise the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the Kumaraswamy distribution that's given on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumaraswamy_distribution), but struggling with the integration.

The probability density function (PDF) for the Kumaraswamy distribution is

$$
f(x) = abx^{a-1}(1-x^a)^{b-1}, 0 < x < 1.
$$

Leaning heavily on some notes and not really understanding what I'm doing, we use a substitution strategy, and set $u = bx^a$ with inverse $x = (\frac{u}{b})^{1/a}$.

To find $\frac{dx}{du}$, we first find $\frac{du}{dx}$:

$$
\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}(bx^a) = abx^{a-1},
$$

and therefore,

$$
\frac{dx}{du} = \frac{1}{\frac{du}{dx}} = \frac{1}{abx^{a-1}}.
$$

Now we substitute:

$$
\int f(x)dx = \int f(h(u)) \frac{dx}{du} du; \\
\int abx^{a-1}(1-x^a)^{b-1} dx = \int abx^{a-1}(1-x^a)^{b-1} (\frac{1}{abx^{a-1}}) du \\
= \int (1-x^a)^{b-1} du \\
= (1 - x^a)^{b-1}
$$

The actual CDF is this:

$$1 - (1 - x^a)^b,$$

and even with my terrible algebra I'm pretty sure you can't rearrange my result to the actual CDF. Appreciate any guidance on performing this integration correctly, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substituting $u = 1-x^a$, $\mathrm{d}u = -ax^{a-1}\mathrm{d}x$ we obtain $$\int ab x^{a-1}(1-x^a)^b\mathrm{d}x = -\int b u^{b-1}\mathrm{d}u = -u^b = -(1-x^a)^b+C.$$
Hence the CDF is of the form $F(x) = C-(1-x^a)^b$ for $x\in (0, 1)$. Since $$0 = F(0) = \lim_{x\to 0^+} F(x) = C-1,$$ we must have $C = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$F(x)=\int_0^{x} abt^{a-1} (1-t^{a})^{b-1}dt$. Put $u=t^{a}$ so that $du=at^{a-1} dt $ and $dt=\frac  1{au^{a/(a-1)}} du$. Now you get $F(x)=b\int_0^{b} (1-u)^{b-1} du=(1-u)^{b}|_0^{x}=1-(1-x^{a})^{b}$.